# regex - delete everything after the first letter

Tags: regex

I am trying to rename some files. I am using a programm called AntRenamer. There is the possibility to use regex for more complex renaming tasks. (Ant Renamer uses the TRegExpr library)

What I have is: **firstname-lastname_001.jpg**

What I want is: **firstname-l_001.jpg**

By using: -.*_

I get: **firstname-_001.jpg**

But I need the first letter of the lastname too. Any ideas?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Just read, Ant Renamer uses the TRegExpr library

Comment: I appended a screenshot to the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for:
`-([A-Za-z]).*_`

Replace to:
`-$1_`

`( )` creates a "capture group" which you can refer to from your replace to expression (`$1`).